# Program crashing using malloc() and free()

Tags: c, malloc, free

I appear to be crashing my program when trying to free memory sections.  The following is the overall structure of my linked lists:

```
typedef struct {
    char                            *dataitem;
    struct listelement              *link;
    int16_t                         wordSize;
    int16_t                         (*libWord)[Q];
    char                            gpioValue;
    struct listelement              *syllables;
}listelement;
```

The program crashes when calling this function:

```
recordedWordsPointer = RemoveItem(recordedWordsPointer);                            // get rid of any junk stored in the recorded buffer
```

Where:

```
volatile listelement *recordedWordsPointer;
```

has stored values in libWord and points to next link if there is another, otherwise NULL.  The following shows what happens when entering the function:

```
listelement * RemoveItem (listelement * listpointer) {
    cpu_irq_disable();
    listelement * tempp = listpointer;

    while( listpointer->syllables != NULL ){
        RemoveSyllable(listpointer->syllables);
    }
    if( listpointer != NULL ){
        tempp = listpointer -> link;
        free (listpointer->dataitem);
        free (listpointer->libWord);
        free (listpointer);
    }
    cpu_irq_enable();   
    return tempp;
}

void RemoveSyllable (listelement * listpointer) {

    while( listpointer->syllables != NULL ){
        RemoveSyllable(listpointer->syllables);
    }
    free (listpointer->dataitem);
    free (listpointer->libWord);
    free (listpointer);
    listpointer = NULL;
    return;
}
```

I was wondering if I am doing something wrong to cause a memory crash?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I was asked to show how I construct the memory locations to help.  I use the following two functions:

```
listelement * AddItem (listelement * listpointer, char* name, int16_t size, int16_t wordLength, int16_t (*words)[Q]) {
    // returns listPointer at the beginning of list
    listelement * lp = listpointer;
    listelement * listPointerTemp;
    char ErrorHandler = NULL;
    // are we at the end of the list?
    if (listpointer != NULL) {
        // move down to the end of the list
        while (listpointer -> link != NULL)
        listpointer = listpointer -> link;
        listPointerTemp = listpointer;
        listpointer -> link = (struct listelement  *) malloc (sizeof (listelement));
        // on fail end links becomes NULL already above
        if(listpointer -> link != NULL){
            listpointer = listpointer -> link;
            listpointer -> link = NULL;
            listpointer -> wordSize = wordLength;
            listpointer -> syllables = NULL;

            listpointer -> dataitem = (char*) malloc ((size + 1)*sizeof(char));
            if(listpointer -> dataitem != NULL){
                for(int i=0; i<size ; i++){
                    listpointer -> dataitem[i] = name[i];
                }
                listpointer -> dataitem[size] = NULL;

                listpointer -> libWord =  (int16_t(*)[Q])malloc(wordLength*Q*sizeof(int16_t));
                if(listpointer -> libWord != NULL){
                    for (int16_t row=0 ; row < wordLength ; row++){
                        for (int col=0 ; col < Q ; col++){
                            listpointer -> libWord[row][col]  = words[row][col];
                        }
                    }
                    ErrorHandler = 1;
                }else{
                    free(listpointer->dataitem);
                    free(listpointer);
                    listPointerTemp -> link = NULL;
                }
            }else{
                free(listpointer);
                listPointerTemp -> link = NULL;
            }
        }
        if(ErrorHandler == NULL){
            //failure
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"Ran out of Memory!  Word not created.\r\n");
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
        }
        return lp;
    } else {
        listpointer = (struct listelement  *) malloc (sizeof (listelement));

        if(listpointer != NULL){
            listpointer -> link = NULL;
            listpointer -> wordSize = wordLength;
            listpointer -> syllables = NULL;

            listpointer -> dataitem = (char*) malloc ((size + 1)*sizeof(char));
            if(listpointer -> dataitem != NULL){
                for(int16_t i=0; i<size ; i++){
                    listpointer -> dataitem[i] = name[i];
                }
                listpointer -> dataitem[size] = NULL;

                listpointer -> libWord =  (int16_t(*)[Q])malloc(wordLength*Q*sizeof(int16_t));
                if(listpointer -> libWord != NULL){
                    for (int16_t row=0 ; row < wordLength ; row++){
                        for (int col=0 ; col < Q ; col++){
                            listpointer -> libWord[row][col]  = words[row][col];
                        }
                    }
                    ErrorHandler = 1;
                }else{
                    free(listpointer->dataitem);
                    free(listpointer);
                    listPointerTemp -> link = NULL;
                }
            }else{
                free(listpointer);
                listPointerTemp -> link = NULL;
            }
        }
        if(ErrorHandler == NULL){
            //failure
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"Ran out of Memory!  Word not created.\r\n");
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
        }
        return listpointer;
    }
}

listelement* AddSyllable (listelement * listpointer, char* name, int16_t size, int16_t wordLength, int16_t (*words)[Q]) {
    // returns listPointer at the beginning of list
    listelement * lp = listpointer;
    listelement * listPointerTemp;
    char ErrorHandler = NULL;
    // are we at the end of the list?
    if (listpointer != NULL) {
        // move down to the end of the list
        while (listpointer -> syllables != NULL)
        listpointer = listpointer -> syllables;
        listPointerTemp = listpointer;
        listpointer -> syllables = (struct listelement  *) malloc (sizeof (listelement));
        // on fail end links becomes NULL already above
        if(listpointer -> syllables != NULL){
            listpointer = listpointer -> syllables;
            listpointer -> link = NULL;
            listpointer -> wordSize = wordLength;

            listpointer -> dataitem = (char*) malloc ((size + 1)*sizeof(char));
            if(listpointer -> dataitem != NULL){
                for(int i=0; i<size ; i++){
                    listpointer -> dataitem[i] = name[i];
                }
                listpointer -> dataitem[size] = NULL;

                listpointer -> libWord =  (int16_t(*)[Q])malloc(wordLength*Q*sizeof(int16_t));
                if(listpointer -> libWord != NULL){
                    for (int16_t row=0 ; row < wordLength ; row++){
                        for (int col=0 ; col < Q ; col++){
                            listpointer -> libWord[row][col]  = words[row][col];
                        }
                    }
                    ErrorHandler = 1;
                }else{
                    free(listpointer->dataitem);
                    free(listpointer);
                    listPointerTemp -> syllables = NULL;
                }
            }else{
                free(listpointer);
                listPointerTemp -> syllables = NULL;
            }
        }
        if(ErrorHandler == NULL){
            //failure
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"Ran out of Memory!  Word not created.\r\n");
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
        }
        return lp;
    } else {
        listpointer = (struct listelement  *) malloc (sizeof (listelement));

        if(listpointer != NULL){
            listpointer -> link = NULL;
            listpointer -> wordSize = wordLength;

            listpointer -> dataitem = (char*) malloc ((size + 1)*sizeof(char));
            if(listpointer -> dataitem != NULL){
                for(int16_t i=0; i<size ; i++){
                    listpointer -> dataitem[i] = name[i];
                }
                listpointer -> dataitem[size] = NULL;

                listpointer -> libWord =  (int16_t(*)[Q])malloc(wordLength*Q*sizeof(int16_t));
                if(listpointer -> libWord != NULL){
                    for (int16_t row=0 ; row < wordLength ; row++){
                        for (int col=0 ; col < Q ; col++){
                            listpointer -> libWord[row][col]  = words[row][col];
                        }
                    }
                    ErrorHandler = 1;
                }else{
                    free(listpointer->dataitem);
                    free(listpointer);
                    listPointerTemp -> syllables = NULL;
                }
            }else{
                free(listpointer);
                listPointerTemp -> syllables = NULL;
            }
        }
        if(ErrorHandler == NULL){
            //failure
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"Ran out of Memory!  Word not created.\r\n");
            usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
        }
        return listpointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the variable marked `volatile`?  Yes, you must be doing something wrong.  You've not shown how the memory is allocated, so we can't tell how you're freeing it wrong.  The pointer to an array of Q `int16_t` looks suspicious; what is the value of `Q`, and why is it a good idea to make that a pointer to an array rather than simply an array?

Comment: Why are you disabling interrupts?

Comment: The volatile is used because I have ISR's that use the same memory locations and don't want them to change those locations via registers to prevent data loss.  I disable interrupts to deconstruct memory to prevent anything weird from happening (constructing onto half deconstructed linked list or anything else I cannot think of)

Comment: Are you running this code in the kernel?  What is an ISR ([AcronymFinder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/ISR.html) didn't help me)?  I know of TSR (terminate-and-stay-resident), but I thought that was a 1990s technology.  Where are you running this code?  Any chance of you producing an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so we can see exactly what you're doing?  Without seeing a version of the code that's failing, we aren't going to be able to help much.  Are you on Linux?  If so, have you used [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: Oh, I see you've added a ream of code for the allocation.  Ouch!  What environment are you actually running in?  USART suggests some sort of embedded environment.  The code you show is not an SSCCE.  I expect people will look at it even so, but you need to work on an SSCCE.

Answer (score 2):

Your RemoveSyllable function doesn't actually set the `syllables` member to NULL. You think it does, inside the routine, but actually you are only changing its value inside the local variable.

Comment: That is a very good observation.  Thanks!  FYI-I don't think that the function goes into RemoveSyllable() when it crashes when using JTAG.  Any additional thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

#### Initial observations

This is more a partial deconstruction of your code than a full-on answer.

Do you not have your compiler warnings turned on?  If not, why not?

```
typedef struct {
    char                            *dataitem;
    struct listelement              *link;
    int16_t                         wordSize;
    int16_t                         (*libWord)[Q];
    char                            gpioValue;
    struct listelement              *syllables;
} listelement
```

Note that the `link` and `syllables` members do not point at the anonymous `struct` that you `typedef` as `listelement`.  They point to some other wholly unrelated structure.  The compiler complains bitterly about this — with good reason.  The fix is simple: change `typedef struct {` to `typedef struct listelement {`.  But we should not have to deal with such a mess in your code.

You also sometimes misuse `NULL`.  For example, `char ErrorHandler = NULL;` generates a warning that a pointer is being converted to an integer of a different size.  `NULL` is not necessarily 0; it is at least sometimes `((void *)0)` or something similar. You also use NULL in place of `'\0'` to set the end byte of a string to the null byte — that elicits a compiler warning too.  These are noisy rather than dreadfully serious, but you should aim for code that compiles silently with a minimum of casting (that is, don't simply slap casts everywhere to shut up the compiler warnings).

You write:

```
    if(listpointer -> link != NULL){
```

Ignoring the placement of the brace (that's subject to legitimate debate), you should have a space after the `if` and you should not have any spaces around `->`.  Similar comments about spaces apply to `while`; it is also conventional to use no space between the function name and the open parenthesis in both calls and definitions.

This warning is serious:

```
usart.c:297:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘RemoveItem’ discards ‘volatile’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
usart.c:253:14: note: expected ‘struct listelement *’ but argument is of type ‘volatile struct listelement *’
```

Basically, you remove the volatility of `recordedWordsPointer` when you call `RemoveItem`, which makes the presence of `volatile` superfluous.  If it is `volatile`, you have to make sure that everywhere that uses it knows that.  Or, more simply, remove the `volatile` qualifier.

There appears to be massive code duplication in each of `AddItem()` and `AddSyllable()`.  You should aim to eliminate about half of each function.

---

Now I've got to work our how you might really use the functions so that I can see what goes wrong.  That's difficult, not least because of the arguments to the `AddItem()` and `AddSyllable()` functions include a mysterious `int16_t (*words)[Q]`.  It would help if you could show a simple `main()` program that invokes these functions with appropriate arguments (which should probably be initialized data structures rather than values read from file).

#### Refactored code

One key refactoring to reduce the volume of code is to create a function that makes a `listelement` given a name, size, number of words, and words.  The `dupstr()` function below is not identical to `strdup()`; it takes a length and duplicates that many characters of a possibly longer string.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { Q = 16 };

typedef struct listelement
{
    char                *dataitem;
    struct listelement  *link;
    int16_t              wordSize;
    int16_t            (*libWord)[Q];
    struct listelement  *syllables;
} listelement;

static int AVR32_USART0 = 0;

static void cpu_irq_disable(void);
static void cpu_irq_enable(void);   
static void usart_write_line(int *ptr, char *msg);
extern void RemoveSyllable(listelement *listpointer);
extern listelement *RemoveItem(listelement *listpointer);
extern listelement *AddSyllable(listelement *listpointer, char *name, int16_t size, int16_t wordLength, int16_t (*words)[Q]);
extern listelement *AddItem(listelement *listpointer, char *name, int16_t size, int16_t wordLength, int16_t (*words)[Q]);

/* Duplicate string - or use POSIX strdup() */
static char *dupstr(const char *name, int16_t size)
{
    char *str = malloc(size+1);
    if (str != NULL)
    {
        memmove(str, name, size);
        str[size] = '\0';
    }
    return str;
}

static listelement *makeElement(const char *name, int16_t size, int16_t wordLength, int16_t (*words)[Q])
{
    listelement *listpointer = (listelement *)malloc(sizeof(listelement));
    // on fail end links becomes NULL already above
    if (listpointer != NULL)
    {
        listpointer->dataitem = dupstr(name, size);
        listpointer->libWord =  (int16_t(*)[Q])malloc(wordLength*Q*sizeof(int16_t));
        if (listpointer->dataitem == NULL || listpointer->libWord == 0)
        {
            free(listpointer->dataitem);
            free(listpointer->libWord);
            free(listpointer);
            listpointer = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            listpointer->link = NULL;
            listpointer->wordSize = wordLength;
            listpointer->syllables = NULL;
            for (int16_t row=0; row < wordLength; row++)
            {
                for (int col=0; col < Q; col++)
                {
                    listpointer->libWord[row][col] = words[row][col];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return listpointer;
}

static void reportError(void)
{
    usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
    usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"Ran out of Memory!  Word not created.\r\n");
    usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
}

listelement *AddItem(listelement *listpointer, char *name, int16_t size, int16_t wordLength, int16_t (*words)[Q])
{
    listelement *lp = listpointer;
    char ErrorHandler = 0;
    if (listpointer != NULL)
    {
        while (listpointer->link != NULL)
            listpointer = listpointer->link;
        listpointer->link = makeElement(name, size, wordLength, words);
        if (listpointer->link != NULL)
        {
            listpointer = listpointer->link;
            ErrorHandler = 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        listpointer = makeElement(name, size, wordLength, words);
        if (listpointer != NULL)
            ErrorHandler = 1;
        lp = listpointer;
    }
    if (ErrorHandler == 0)
        reportError();
    return lp;
}

listelement *AddSyllable(listelement *listpointer, char *name, int16_t size, int16_t wordLength, int16_t (*words)[Q])
{
    listelement *lp = listpointer;
    char ErrorHandler = 0;
    if (listpointer != NULL)
    {
        while (listpointer->syllables != NULL)
            listpointer = listpointer->syllables;
        listpointer->syllables = makeElement(name, size, wordLength, words);
        if (listpointer->syllables != NULL)
            ErrorHandler = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        listpointer = makeElement(name, size, wordLength, words);
        if (listpointer != NULL)
            ErrorHandler = 1;
        lp = listpointer;
    }
    if (ErrorHandler == 0)
        reportError();
    return lp;
}

listelement *RemoveItem(listelement *listpointer)
{
    cpu_irq_disable();
    listelement * tempp = listpointer;

    while (listpointer->syllables != NULL)
    {
        RemoveSyllable(listpointer->syllables);
    }
    if (listpointer != NULL)
    {
        tempp = listpointer->link;
        free (listpointer->dataitem);
        free (listpointer->libWord);
        free (listpointer);
    }
    cpu_irq_enable();   
    return tempp;
}

void RemoveSyllable(listelement *listpointer)
{
    while (listpointer->syllables != NULL)
    {
        RemoveSyllable(listpointer->syllables);
    }
    free(listpointer->dataitem);
    free(listpointer->libWord);
    free(listpointer);
    listpointer = NULL;
    return;
}

static void cpu_irq_disable(void) { AVR32_USART0 = 0; }
static void cpu_irq_enable(void)  { AVR32_USART0 = 1; }   
static void usart_write_line(int *ptr, char *msg)
{
    *ptr = !*ptr;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", msg);
}

int main(void)
{
    listelement *recordedWordsPointer = 0;
    recordedWordsPointer = RemoveItem(recordedWordsPointer);
}
```

I've not proven that every single change in there is sound, but I am sure that the `addSyllable()` and `addItem()` functions are a whole heap easier to read with the `makeElement()` function doing most of the repeated work.  There is undoubtedly room for improvement.  The code needs a working `main()` that really exercises the functions (and the code above does not qualify).

I have reservations about how the pointer to the array is being handled, but I have not taken the code to a machine where I can usefully run `valgrind` (Mac OS X 10.8.x unfortunately is not supported by `valgrind`, yet).  I have not proved that it is wrong; I am suspicious that it is wrong.  It would help me no end to see the calling code, and the definition of the variable passed as a pointer to an array.